# Passing same Model/ViewModel to multiple Partial Views (tabs in jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

A bit new to .Net + MVC dev.

**background...** in my lil app i have 3 tables ... applications, databases, and app_db_support table. The 3rd table has fks to the first 2 and stores associations.

**Want to...** add new applications and associated dbs via a tabbed jquery form setup.

**Approach...** trying to use partial views in tabs to break up applications, databases, and associated support info.

Main.cshtml code

```
<div id="dialog" title="Add Application" style="display: none">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#application">Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="#database">Database</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="application">
            @Html.Partial("_AddAppForm", ... );
       </div>

        <div id="database">
            <p>DB Partial view here </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question...** I'd like to be able to use a ViewModel for all the underlying models and pass that to each of the partials. Being new on the controls, I am a tad lost around how to pass the same instance of the ViewModel, say MyAppViewModel that could have the 3 models in it. Since the tabs will all be associated with a single app, a single viewmodel should be able to handle it.

**Alternatives...** again, being new, if there are better ways of going about this (hence background info), I'd be happy to look at alternatives, especially if they are easier. :)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of what you might do:

ViewModel

```
namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class AppsViewModel
    {        
        public IEnumerable<Applicaiton> Applications { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Database> Databases { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AppsViewModel vm = new AppsViewModel();
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()){
        vm.Applications = db.Applications;
        vm.Databases = db.Databases;
    }

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddApplication(AppsViewModel model)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()){
        db.Applications.Add(model.Application);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDatabase(AppsViewModel model)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()){
        db.Databases.Add(model.Database);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View

```
@model Project.AppsViewModel
<div id="dialog" title="Add Application" style="display: none">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#application">Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="#database">Database</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="application">
            @foreach (var app in Model.Applications){
                //render your view
            }
        </div>

        <div id="database">
            @foreach (var app in Model.Databases){
                //render your view
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. If that was a solution please mark it as the solution :)